# Some keys on keyboard won't work

Tags: keyboard

I haven't used a laptop for 2 weeks, and now it turns out that some of the keys on the keyboard don't work. I don't know the reason, laptop is itself about 6 years old. The problem never happened before, could this be a hardware-related problem? How could this happen by itself?

Comment: What happens if you use an external keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Test with an external USB keyboard, [available for US$5](https://www.fivebelow.com/flexible-foldable-silicone-keyboard.html) or less. If that works, then the issue is with the internal keyboard or wiring (e.g., a loose connector).

- Reboot (full Restart), to see if the issue is software, not hardware.
- Check that all the keys are in the "up" position (lift each *gently* with a small screwdriver or needle to check).
- If all else fails, open the laptop *per* manufacturer's directions and check the the keyboard cable is tight.

Replacement keyboards are available, or just keep using a USB keyboard.

Comment: Before opening the laptop, I suggest hitting the faulty keys repeatedly a few times with moderate force and also trying to blow out any debris.

Comment: Ah! *Percussive maintenance*, as we call it in the industry. See http://matznerd.com/story-of-the-broken-steamship-engine/

Comment: Yes, but not *too* percussive, and as a diagnostic step, if that causes more keys to stop working then the keyboard connector cable may be working its way loose. Shaking the crumbs out may confirm that (vibrational failure mode experimentation).